# Outbound network traffic linearly growing with offchain protocol and recommendations for handling traffic growth

Tags: networking, offchain, gossip

## Issue

We are experiencing a behaviour on our standalone/parachain node where the `Network Bps` on our cloud provider linearly increases throughout the lifecycle of our protocol. The increase continues without restraint until there's a tremendous amount of outbound/inbound traffic, accelerating the costs of the service.

[image]

## Overview of protocol

Every session (6 hours) we run a certain multi-party computation (t-ECDSA DKG) offchain and begin using Substrate's network layer `GossipEngine` to gossip messages as part of the protocol to other peers on the network. This leads us to believe that we should be seeing a *constant* outbound `Bps sent` since we clean up the existing system by replacing it with the execution of a new MPC. However, the graph indicates this is not the case. Instead, it seems like we *are not* cleaning things up and instead every DKG's outbound traffic is compounding on one another.

### Where we gossip messages

#### Gossiping

We gossip messages in 3 different places for some auxiliary protocols we run.

- [For gossiping messages related to the DKG/Sign protocol](https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/blob/master/dkg-gadget/src/messages/dkg_message.rs#L168-L171)
- [For gossiping DKG public key for on-chain purposes](https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/blob/master/dkg-gadget/src/messages/public_key_gossip.rs#L135-L138)
- [For gossiping misbehaviour reports](https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/blob/master/dkg-gadget/src/messages/misbehaviour_report.rs#L141-L144)

#### Validating

In this latest graph we are using the `GossipValidator::validate` function with `ProcessAndDiscard` in hopes of avoiding any unnecessary outbound re-broadcasting. Nonetheless this hasn't fixed the situation.

- [The implementation today is configurable over some # of re-broadcasts](https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/blob/master/dkg-gadget/src/gossip.rs#L110-L115)

### Questions

- Perhaps there's parts of the gossip engine I haven't grasped yet but otherwise what are some recommended ways of handling/debugging these situations?
- Are there side-effects I should be aware for the gossip engine?